# XPath / XmlCompiledTransform: Test parent with XPath function

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xpath, xslcompiledtransform

I am not sure if I'm really doing a mistake or if this is just not working properly:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1 or parent::position() = 1">
   <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

If the current node is the first child, or it's parent is the first child, then do something special.

The problem is "parent::position() = 1" .. with .net's XmlCompiledTransform I get

**Expected end of the expression, found '('. ...sition() = 1 or parent ::position -->(<-- = 1.**

Now, apparently it doesn't like that position() function in the second part, but.. how do I get the parent's position? How do I, generally, *combine* XPath functions with XPaths in tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, +1.

**You need to define what is meant by *position* of the parent**.

```
parent::node()[position() = 1]
```

**is always `true()`** when the parent node exists (is `false()` only if the context node is the document node `/` as this node is the top node in the tree and doesn't have a parent), because any node in a tree (well-formed XML document) by definition can have at most one parent node.

**Most likely, you want to test that the parent element is the first in document order among its siblings**. One way to test for this is:

```
not(parent::node()/preceding-sibling::*)
```

**So, the complete code becomes**:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1 or not(parent::node()/preceding-sibling::*)">        
   <!-- do something -->        
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in using `parent::node()` over `parent::*`?

Comment: @Tomalak: They are different. `parent::node()` gives you the parent in all cases when it exists, while `parent::*` if issued with the top element as the context node, doesn't select any node at all, however the parent exists -- it just isn't an element.

Comment: You're right, at the document element it would indeed make a difference. Not necessarily for this case, as there can be no preceding siblings in that position, but nevertheless.